# Как мне сделать кнопку которая очистит то что напечатала другая кнопка?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div class="time"> <button class="buton" onclick="document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=Date()">Время сейчас?</button>
  <p id="test"></p>
</div>
```

На JS код для показа времени есть , но мне нужна кнопка которая очистит то время которое написала.

Comment: <div class="time">  
                <button class="buton" onclick="document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=Date()">Время сейчас?</button>
                <p id="test"></p>
        </div>

Comment: Причем здесь шарп и плюсы?

Comment: Не работает она не очищает время которое пишет при нажатии на кнопку "Время Сейчас"

Answer (score 0):

Если оставить исходный код то, например, так:

```html
<div class="time">
  <button class="buton" onclick="document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=Date()">Время сейчас?</button>
  <button class="buton" onclick="document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=''">Очистить</button>
  <p id="test"></p>
</div>
```

Но писать весь код прямо в атрибуте -- не самое лучшее решение. Можно сделать, например, так:

```js
const field = document.getElementById('test');
document.getElementById('get').addEventListener('click', get_date);
document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', clear_date);

function get_date() {
  field.innerHTML = new Date();
  return;
}

function clear_date() {
  field.innerHTML = '';
  return;
}
```

```html
<div class="time">
  <button class="buton" id="get">Время сейчас?</button>
  <button class="buton" id="clear">Очистить</button>
  <p id="test"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

можно воспользоваться стандартными возможностями html форм.

```html
<form class='time'>
<input disabled id='test'>
<input type='button' value='date' onclick='getElementById("test").value=Date();'>
<input type='reset' value='clear'>
<input type='date'>
<input type='time'>
</form>
```